# Do Arcane Caster Levels Count as Cleric Levels for Turning/Rebuking Checks?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, cleric, wizard

If I am a Wizard, with no levels of Cleric, and I gain a domain power (through a prestige class<sup>1</sup>) that Turns X-Creatures as a Cleric Turns Undead; does my arcane caster level equal Cleric levels for that purpose?

**Example (Arachnomancer)**

**1<sup>st</sup> Level:** Poison Save Bonus, Handle Spiders, **Spider Domain**

> **Spider Domain:** Rebuke or command spiders **as an evil cleric** rebukes or commands undead. You can use this abilities a number of times per day equal to 3 + your Cha modifier.

**Cleric level** seems important due to the following table:

[image: Turning Undead]

If I have no "cleric level" is the Rebuke or Command Spiders essentially doomed as ineffective?

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Earthshaker (Dragon Magazine) gets Earth Domain, which grants Rebuking/Commanding Earth Creatures.</sub>

Comment: [Related](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/41320/8610), I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The prestige class arachnomancer (*Drow of the Underdark* 65-8) says

  > You gain access to the Spider domain and the granted power associated with the domain (rebuke spiders as an evil cleric rebukes undead, a number of times per day equal to 3 + your Cha modifier). (65)

  Hence a level 1 arachnomancer rebukes spiders like a level 1 cleric rebukes undead—no matter what other abilities the arachnomancer possesses—, and that's terrible.
- The prestige class earthshaker (*Dragon* #314 57-9) says that the creature

  > gains the Earth domain's granted power, substituting his earthshaker levels for cleric levels. (58)

  And, yes, that's *also* terrible, but it's *worse* because while expected entry into the prestige class arachnomancer is at about character level 5, expected entry into the prestige class earthshaker is at about character level *9*. Your granted power isn't just bringing almost nothing to the table, it's actually insulting.

## Extra domains in general

Although earthshaker predates *Complete Divine*, that version of the arachnomancer was released long after *Complete Divine*.<sup>1</sup> Both, however, seem to follow similarly the *Complete Divine*'s vague rules on Extra Domains which, in part, says

> If a noncleric enters a prestige class that allows access to a domain, the character still gains access to the domain. She can use the granted power bestowed by the domain normally. (20)

*Complete Divine*, of course, doesn't actually *say* what *normally* means here, but, apparently, based on the anecdotal evidence from the above two classes, the game takes *normally* to mean here that the creature treats its levels in the prestige class as cleric levels, combining with *nothing* unless the text indicates otherwise. Which, let me say again, is terrible.

#### Negotiate with the DM

I suggest asking the DM to allow the arachnomancer to rebuke spiders like an evil cleric of *twice* the creature's arachnomancer level. While that's *still* terrible, it does sort incentivize staying in arachnomancer, because it (*ahem*) bugs some DMs when players have a bunch of a different classes on their character sheets. Creatures likely enter earthshaker too late for this quick-and-dirty fix to do any good, and thrice (maximum 20th) earthshaker level might be overreaching, but it couldn't hurt to ask.

---

<sup>1</sup> The original arachnomancer was, confusingly enough, introduced in *Underdark*, an early but still *3.5* product.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Unless you have some trait which says otherwise, caster levels do not stack with cleric levels for the purpose of turning. However, most classes which turn like a cleric use that class's levels instead of cleric levels, and all "turning class" levels stack. (Though as far as I know, it's still an open question how e.g. a spider turning class stacks with an undead turning class).

To answer your second question, if you only have one level in a turning class, you aren't likely to do a lot of turning. Those turn attempts aren't useless though; you could use them to power various other options. *Complete Divine* is probably the best source for non-standard things to do with your turn attempts. Remember to look at Night Sticks if you start to run out.

Comment: Uncertain I can use Turn Spiders to fuel Divine Feats that have Turn Undead as a prerequisite. Do  you have a source for that?

Comment: @Ruut I do not, and I think your doubt is well founded. I had forgotten divine metamagic called specifically for turn/rebuke undead. Answer updated to reflect that.